# Binding viewmodel within ItemsControl to custom user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm modernising an application (from Windows Forms and VB.Net to WPF) that displays a list of recent messages to a user. I've created a `MessageViewModel`, a `MessagesListViewModel` and two custom user controls `MessageListUserControl` and `MessageUserControl`.

Messages are listed using an `ItemsControl` in the `MessageListUserControl` in a vertical stack panel and are rendered using a `MessageuserControl`. However, all of the messages have the `Message` property set to `null`, rather than the current message.

I've included below my code, if anybody has any ideas about how to fix the bindings, I'd be extremely grateful as this is my first go with WPF.

***MessageViewModel***

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class MessageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _sender;

        private string _subject;

        private string _content;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Sender
        {
            get { return _sender; }
            set
            {
                _sender = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Sender");
            }
        }

        public string Subject
        {
            get { return _subject; }
            set
            {
                _subject = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Subject");
            }
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set
            {
                _content = value.Trim();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Content");
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***MessageListViewModel***

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class MessageListViewModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> _messages;

        public ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> Messages
        {
            get { return _messages; }
        }

        public MessageListViewModel()
        {
            _messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>();
        }

        #region Methods
        public void AddMessage(string sender, string subject, string content)
        {

            var vm = new MessageViewModel()
            {
                Sender = sender,
                Subject = subject,
                Content = content,
            };
            _messages.Insert(0, vm); // Insert it at the top of the list.
        }
        #endregion // Methods
    }
}
```

***MessageUserControl***

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.MessageUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="MessageCtrl" Background="White"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Name="lblSender" Text="Sender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="5"/>
                <TextBlock Name="txtSender" Text="{Binding Path=Sender, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5"/>

                <TextBlock Name="lblSubject" Text="Subject" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="5"/>
                <TextBlock Name="txtSubject" Text="{Binding Path=Subject, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" Name="txtMessageContent" Text="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

***MessageListUserControl***

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.MessageListUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White" x:Name="MessagesListCtrl"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MessagesStack" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:MessageControl Message="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The result ends up looking like the following, with an empty subject, sender and content:

[image: Empty message details]

I've also tried setting the binding in the `DataTemplate` in `MessageListUserControl` to `{Binding /}` as found [here](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf) with no success, as well as setting `DataContext={Binding}`.

When I move the template XAML for the single message display directly into the `DataTemplate`, everything works fine but I wish to separate it into a separate control to perform some extra logic on it.

Comment: A general rule for UserControls: *Never* set their DataContext explicitly (as you do in `DataContext="{Binding Message ...}"`), because that prevents inheriting a DataContext, e.g. when you put it in a DataTemplate used for the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl. The effect is that your binding `Message="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"` won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. I've removed that from the `MessageUserControl` now, and have used WPF Inspector to inspect the application. it looks like the DataContext for the `MessageUserControl` is null, so I tried setting that (`DataContext={Binding}`) with no luck - it's still null!

Comment: Try removing Content="{Binding}" ! Keeping everything else intact. Also remove Mode=TwoWay from various places as they are not needed at all.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Just tried that, no luck. I've updated the question.

Comment: When you put a UserControl in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl, it inherits its DataContext from its container (a ContentPresenter). The object in the DataContent is the corresponding element of the ItemsSource collection. See [Styling and Templating an ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx#DataTemplating_ItemsControl).

Comment: @Clemens Spot on! That's done the trick by the looks of things. I removed the DataContext from the `MessageUserControl` and removed all of the `Mode=TwoWay` entries and now it appears to be working. Thanks! If you can provide an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I have a similar situation and the "MessageUserControl" (my equivalent of it) are nicely rendered. It shows also the correct values (Sender, Content,...). In my case the "MessageUserControl" has also some buttons. I want to add logic of these buttons to the "MessageControlViewModel" but for some reason it seems that the MessageUserControl is not "linked" its corresponding the ViewModel. How is the binding realized? I want to have a "Message" object and some `RelayCommands` in the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Message` property from

`<local:MessageControl Message="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" />`

It is not needed at all.

Remove `DataContext` from `MessageControl` which you have already done now.

Everything remaining same, now it will work.

The `DataTemplate` will get it's `DataContext` automatically as `MessageViewModel`.